# COALESCE two dates returns binary?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

Why does `COALESCE(date1,date2)` return `Blob`(binary)? Both columns are of type `DATETIME`.

Here's the complete sql query:

```
SELECT COALESCE( last_modified, date_purchased )As LastModifiedOrPurchased
FROM Orders
ORDER BY COALESCE( last_modified, date_purchased )DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I'm normally using SQL-Server as rdbms but need to write a synchronization tool. Now i'm trying to select one of two dates. If `last_modified` is null `date_purchased` should be returned.

But even if there are multiple records where both dates are not null, the query returns just `Blob`. How to get the correct last date?

**Edit**: on [**SQL-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/35cae/3/0) it is not reproducable with MySql 5.1.61 (i'm on 5.0.51).

Comment: Have you tried it on command-line? Or what do you use to fire the query? And what's the datatype of those columns?

Comment: @tombom: I have tried it from MySql workbench 5.2.34 and from Visual Studio. Btw, i'm on windows 2008.

Comment: Yes, I would have wondered, if it were reproducable. A lot of clients out there have problems displaying data correctly or think they do the user a favour, i.e. I'm using Toad, which will not display `tinyint` correctly (it uses just checkboxes then) and `NULL` values won't be displayed at all, so you can't tell if it's NULL or empty string. Nonetheless I can still recommend Toad, though. The problem is your client!

Comment: Since there's only two columns, why not use IFNULL()

Comment: @Jack: That works also (edited my answer accordingly):

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bug that has been fixed: **[bug-35662](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35662)**

> [28 Mar 2008 22:44] Patrick Crews
>
> Description:
>   `COALESCE(date, date)` returns varbinary on **5.0.51a for Windows** XP 32bit (only tested this flavor)
>
> `COALESCE(date,date)` returns date on Mac OS
>
> ...
>   ...
>   ...
>
> [31 Mar 2008 17:41] Omer BarNir
>   The bug was fixed in 5.0.52 and was not observed when testing 5.0.56 - closing

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why this happens in MySql Workbench (and also MS Visual Studio). But i have found a workaround. I just cast the result to `DATETIME` and it works as expected:

```
SELECT CAST(COALESCE( last_modified, date_purchased )AS DATETIME)As LastModifiedOrPurchased
FROM Orders
ORDER BY COALESCE( last_modified, date_purchased )DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Edit: as Jack has commented, `IFNULL` works also:

```
SELECT IFNULL( last_modified, date_purchased )As LastModifiedOrPurchased
FROM Orders
ORDER BY IFNULL( last_modified, date_purchased )DESC
LIMIT 1;
```