# Are implicit data type conversion rules for COALESCE (a,b,...) the same than for IN (a,b,...)

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce, sql-function

I have [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662641/coalesce-extrage-results-on-dates-and-strings) found some difficulties with data conversions of dates within a COALESCE call and finally concluded that the implicit data type conversions rules aplying for COALESCE list elements are the same than the rules used by [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

From [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html):

> If one of the arguments is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column and the other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp before the comparison is performed. This is done to be more ODBC-friendly. **Note that this is not done for the arguments to IN()!** To be safe, always use complete datetime, date, or time strings when doing ? comparisons. For example, to achieve best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type.

Is it true that COALESCE and IN share the same type conversion rules?
If the answer is yes, **I wonder whether those rules are the same for any function with two ore more input parameters**.

Comment: The rules vary depending on the function.  You'll need to check each function individually.  This is one reason that I would suggest that *explicit* type conversion is much safer that replying on *implicit* type conversion.  It may be more to type, but you have much more obvious behaviour and control.

Comment: How does this affect your query? COALESCE() just checks if parameters are NULL, until it finds a non-NULL value. The data type is irrelevant.

Comment: @Federico You have an example on the question I have linked above but an example is: SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE COALESCE(date1, '20000101') < '20131219'

Comment: Ah, I understand. If you use MySQL 5.6, you may try this syntax: DATE '20000101'. But the most reliable way to do it is probably the one suggested in the docs: CAST().